# How to avoid taxes when a stock you own is taken over in a cash deal?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, corporate-acquisition

I own shares of company A in a personal, non-tax advantaged account.  Company A is being acquired by company B at a premium in an all cash deal, but I'd like to avoid the taxes associated with selling stocks if possible.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can't you keep your shares and not sell?

Comment: @Vilx- No, that's what an "all cash buyout" is.  Any shares you hold in an investment account in such a company on the settlement date (which, if this is Activision/MSFT, won't be until next year sometime) are converted to their equivalent cash value per the buyout agreement and the shares disappear.  There would have been a shareholder vote prior to the deal where shareholders can elect to support or reject the deal, but if a majority vote to sell then everyone has to sell - there is no choice.

Comment: @J... - That's weird. How can someone _force_ me to sell something I own? Doesn't that go against some basic human rights or constitution or something? Well, I guess there are laws that support it. But man, investing is **weird**.

Comment: @J... - Wait. Does that mean that a majority vote of other shareholders can screw me over in other ways too? Can they vote to force just ME to sell? Can they vote to confiscate my shares without anything in return? Or maybe they can vote to force me to pay to the company whatever amount of money they choose? Or... so many ideas... Surely not?

Comment: @Vilx- That sounds like it deserves an entire separate question.

Comment: @Vilx- Yes, it's best to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Vilx - As a shareholder, you own a  percentage of the company but you do not own any of the physical assets nor do you have any direct control over how the company is run.  At best, you may have voting rights for electing the board of directors members who in turn hires upper management.  If the BOD decides to sell the company, in a merger, your shares are converted into the buyer's shares.  If it's a cash buy out, you receive cash.  There are no basic human rights being violated here.

Comment: @Vilx- many countries have rules which allow a majority owner to force minority owners to sell to them if the majority is above a certain percentage - stops a hold out with 1 share preventing someone with all the other shares taking the company private.  In the UK this is 90%, in the US it varies by state: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze-out

Comment: @Vilx: Yes, a majority of shareholders can vote to screw you over in all kinds of ways, but there's an equal protection sort of effect -- they can't single you out, you will be treated exactly as any other holder of the same share class, in proportion to your stake.  And the company executives and board of directors have a "fiduciary duty" that prevents them from doing such things without a shareholder vote.  Making your shares worthless without anything in return is definitely on the table, via overcompensating employees, stock dilution, or losing the entire company in a lawsuit.

Comment: The stock can be transferred to a corporation and then the corporation gets the capital-gain. Also, the transferring party must be at least 80% shareholder of the corporation. Finally, the corporation needs a business purpose other than personal-holding-company. https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.351-1

Comment: I suggest that can't be done in your jurisdiction, or any other, for the simple reason that a sale is a sale..

When you own shares in company A, can you explain what difference a personal, non-tax advantaged account might make?

When Company A is being acquired by company B, what difference might that being at a premium make?

When the acquisition is through an all-cash deal, what difference might that make?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

US centric answer:

An all-cash deal is a sale so there is no way to avoid taxes when there's a cash buy out of a position in a non-sheltered account.

Comment: OP hasn't told us explicitly, but this is probably the ATVI/MSFT deal.  In that case it won't settle until next year, likely, so one strategy here, depending, might be to start selling some of the shares early if the price is reasonable.  That way, at least, you can spread the damage over two tax years and maybe limit it somewhat depending what OP's bracket and deduction situation is.  Depends on how long OP has held the shares for, also.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is right, in that a cash acquisition is in effect a forced sale for cash, so gains are realized and recognized and hence taxable.  But if you **really** want to defer paying taxes on the gain, there are options.  For example qualified opportunity funds, discussed by IRS [here](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/businesses/invest-in-a-qualified-opportunity-fund) and Kiplinger [here](https://www.kiplinger.com/article/investing/t054-c032-s014-opportunity-zone-funds-can-help-with-capital-gains.html). Note that you much be a qualified investor.  I know this probably should be a comment but I am new to this particular Stack Exchange and don't have the reputation required for a comment.

Comment: these won't help though in this situation since the OP is already invested. There are a lot of investment options with tax deferral component (e.g.: Real estate), but there's no point listing them for the OP who has a specific situation

Comment: Did read the links?  You must not have have because the explicit design of the QOZ provision created in 2017 is to allow deferral of realized capital gains to encourage investment in those areas.  So it's not "no point," it is **the** point.

Comment: And how is this point helping the OP?